# Setting an absolute positioned div to overlap one regular div but not another

Tags: html, css

I have a page that's set up with a split pane - top and bottom (divs using calc() for their height), with the top div having an absolutely positioned div that overlays the top div. HTML + CSS below from https://jsfiddle.net/b2mb79ev/1/

```
<div id="everything">
    <div id="top">
        <div id="free"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>


#everything {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

#top {
  height: calc(50%);
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

#free {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

#bottom {
  height: calc(50%);
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,255,0,0.6);
}
```

However I want the absolutely positioned div not to intrude into the bottom div. I want the bottom div to always be in a 'higher' layer. In the jsfiddle I don't want the yellow bit going into the green bit.

But from what I can gather the top and bottom divs always have the same level because they are just regularly flowed elements and won't take any notice of z-index. I can use z-index to have the absolutely positioned div above both or beneath both, but not one above and one underneath?

Is there a way to do what I'd like?

Comment: You mean like this https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/b2mb79ev/2/?

Comment: That was too quick :-). Stick it as answer so I can give you some credit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set a non-static position (e.g. `position:relative`) on the #bottom div to give the [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) you're after.

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/b2mb79ev/2/)**

```
#bottom {
  height: calc(50%);
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.6);
  position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I feel daft it's a one-line answer but rather that than the mess of absolute divs I was considering!